# Is there a more efficient way of drawing a pixel than GL_POINTS?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

In a program I am intending to be writing to lots of pixels individually.  I'm guessing that using a vbo, shaders and `GL_POINTS` isn't very efficent.  A thought I had was to draw two triangles across the whole screen and then write to every pixel in the fragment shader, although i'm not sure how efficient that would be?

I am using openGL 3 so none of the deprecated functions are being used.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. THere are POINTS, there is writing to a texure and blitting it to the screen, there are fragment shaders, and possibly lots of other paths which might be useful to reach a specific goal.

Comment: @derhass I have a lot of 'particles' which are one pixel in size that i would be intending to draw.

Comment: Well. Using a POINT per particle does not sound terribly bad then.

Comment: @derhass I believe there are more efficient ways

Comment: @Ryxuma: What makes you think that? As long as the points are sparsely distributed it's actually a very efficient way to go about this. Heck point sprites have been introduced to allow drawing complex shaped particles using GL_POINTS primitive rendering operations.

Comment: @datenwolf I don't know, I just assumed that doing it in the fragment shader would be faster

Comment: @Ryxuma: What makes you think that. A fragment shader can not specify target pixel positions for a fragment. So you'd effectively pass the fragment shader a full viewport quad so that it runs over each and every pixels. And then you'd have for each fragment to test, if it's actually covered by a point (which would make a naive implementation complexity O(n·m) n being the number of pixels in the viewport and m being the number of points in the list of points to draw). Actually fragment shaders are the place where most performance hits are created and need to be optimized.

Comment: @datenwolf surely i could create a sampler2D in my main program and use that?

Comment: @Ryxuma: And in which way would the sampler2D help you? You still have to address every pixel on the screen for this to be universally usable. And the sampler2D just helps you with getting the data in, but it does nothing to reduce the complexits. Say the sampler2D contained a list of all points to be drawn, you'd still have to iterate over every sample in the texture for every pixel you're drawing. Turning this again into a O(n·m) complex problem. You could of course draw the points at the final screen locations in the texture to be used, but that would be a simple textured quad then.

Comment: @Ryxuma: Points are not pixels. GL does not give you enough control over the size and shape of point primitives to reliably make this association. Sometimes they will be square, but if you have anti-aliasing enabled they will often be round. The rules for the origin of the point differ depending on whether the width is even or odd as well. If you need to guarantee that your points are always 1 pixel in size, you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman If you are in 2D you can set the size of a point (it is by default the size of one pixel) and in 3D you cannot change them (at least in lwjgl) and they are always 1 pixel in size no matter your distance to them

Comment: Actually, you cannot. Sub-pixel precision, shape and a number of other factors mean that the 1 pixel width you requested is not guranteed to be positioned or shaped where you want it. Enable `GL_POINT_SMOOTH` or multisampling (on many implementations) to see immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered instanced rendering ? Drawing even 2 pixel-sized triangles may be faster than drawing points.

Have a look at `glDrawArraysInstanced`and `glVertexAttribDivisor` (for applying different colors etc.).

If you particles have an acceleration or any deterministic position change algorithm, you can even apply this change in the vertex shader to limit the space occupied by the associated VBO (no need to keep positions) and the CPU time (only a few GL call is required to draw AND animate the whole particle system).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. My idea of drawing 2 triangles each was neglecting the fact that he clearly doesn't want to draw 1 fragment sprites :p Let the assume drawing points with VBO is the best approach !

Answer (score 1):

In the new OpenGL you can bind a [FBO with no attachment](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_no_attachments.txt) and use [image output in a fragment shader](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) to achieve a similar functionality. However, poor performance can be expected because of (possibly) highly irregular memory access patterns, which can be fatal on GPU. But perhaps you can achieve slightly better performance than when rasterizing points.